# Html, css, bootsrap, how to aline element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf,bootstap,css for the view. I couldn't aline the button and level as shown in the picture:-

[image]

## Update:

Here is the source code:-

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
              xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
              layout:decorator="shared-fragments/page"
              th:inline="text">
        <head lang="en">
            <link th:href="@{/datepicker/css/datepicker3.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content" class="container">

            <th:block th:include="fragments/common :: top"/>
            
     <!-- ** This is code shows the green button **  -->
      <div class="pull-right"
                 th:with="hasKeyField=${!process.rowView.getAllFields().?[systemName==T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.Field).KEY_FIELD].isEmpty()}">
                <a class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"
                   th:if="${hasKeyField}"
                   th:href="${#mvc.url('VC#newRow').arg(0, project.id).arg(1, process.id).build()}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span th:text="#{view.common.new}">New</span>
                </a>
            </div>
    
            <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="${kf}
                           ? ${#mvc.url('VC#save').arg(0, project.id).arg(1, process.id).arg(2, kf).build()}
                           : ${#mvc.url('VC#saveNewRow').arg(0, project.id).arg(1, process.id).build()}" method="post">
                <th:block th:each="field : ${uniqueEditFields}">
                    <th:block th:switch="${field.projectField.type.actualType}">
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).STRING}"
                                  th:with="readOnly=${kf} and ${#strings.equals(field.projectField.systemName, T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.Field).KEY_FIELD)}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: text-field (${field}, ${data}, ${readOnly}, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).TIME}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: time-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).DATE}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: date-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).BOOLEAN}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: boolean-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).LIST}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: list-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).DECIMAL}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: text-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).NUMBER}">
                            <div th:replace="fragments/components :: number-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).PHOTOSET}">
                            <div>{PHOTOS HIDDEN}</div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.FieldType).FILE}">
                            <div>{PHOTO HIDDEN}</div>
                        </th:block>
                        <th:block th:case="*">
                            <div th:if="${!field.projectField.type.isCalculation()}"
                                 th:replace="fragments/components :: text-field (${field}, ${data}, false, ${errors})"></div>
                        </th:block>
                    </th:block>
                </th:block>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" th:id="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.Field).KEY_FIELD}"
                           th:name="${T(com.ahkgroup.projectmanagement.domain.definition.Field).KEY_FIELD}" th:value="${kf}"/>
                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        <th:block layout:fragment="scripts">
            <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                        language: [[${#ctx.locale}]],
                        format: [[#{data.format.date.js}]]
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </th:block>
        </html>
```

How can align the button with the from and remove extra space from Key field. So that it looks consistence with rest of the element. Please advice me. Thanks!

Comment: Provide code and show us what you have done so far else this will lead to downvotes

Comment: set a class to button and add `margin:0`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bootstrap classes : pull-left and pull-right